# Division by zero handled differently

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, postgresql

I am not sure if this has been answered before in S.O, but I couldn't find any answers googling to explain this behaviour in various databases. so I thought I would clarify this here from experts.

When I run this query in Oracle, Postgresql, mysql and sql-server, I get  varying  results.

**Oracle 11g**

```
select count(1/0) from dual;
```

> ORA-01476: divisor is equal to zero

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/751

**SQL-Server 2017**

```
select count(1/0) ;

1
```

but `select 1/0` gives error.

> Divide by zero error encountered

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2be41/2

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/185a6/7

**PostgreSQL 9.6**

> ERROR: division by zero

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/340e0/80

**Mysql 5.6**

```
select count(1/0) ;

0
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2be41/10

Why these differences in implementations?

Comment: Hi Kaushik, it' interesting to see you as asking a Question. Thanks for rare but nice question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`count()` counts the number of rows or the non-`NULL` values of the expression.

When the expression is constant, then it returns the number of rows.

What you are seeing is the question of when and whether the constant is evaluated, and the different way that the databases handle this situation.

Oracle and Postgres are clearly trying to evaluate the constant.  To be honest, I'm not sure if these are run-time or compile-time errors.

SQL Server postpones the evaluation until needed -- and it is never needed.  So, it counts the number of rows.

MySQL is the strange one.  It returns `NULL` for divide-by-zero.  This is not standard behavior, but also not entirely unreasonable.  `COUNT(NULL)` returns `0`.

Comment: The sql server explanation doesn't make sense to me. Why wouldn't `count(1/0)` throw an error similar to `1/0`?

Comment: @JoePhillips . . . Here is an example:  http://rextester.com/WXPT30639.

Answer (score 5):

In mysql  there is a  specific mode (enabled or disable)

`ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO`

that manage this situation and in your case seems 
 disable  (you should check for proper mode value) so you apparently see  a wrong (or unexpected result) but is simply a configuration for error handling

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-expressions.html